# Draw on the custom image view in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, android-view, android-drawable

I am working on a drawing app. And I already create a draw view that allow user to draw on the view.

The problem is , when I draw on it , it exceed the area of the image (please refer to the picture, the yellow line is exceeed the actual photo area), how can I stick the canvas size to the actual image ?

And how the imageview be zoomable? That means when user click on pen button, it draw, when user click again then it become zoom function.

Thanks. The zoom function can be tackle later and the problem of exceed area need to fix first

[image]

Here is the custom draw view in xml

```
  <com.example.tool.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is the java

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView {

    private int color = Color.BLACK;
    private float width = 4f;
    private List<Holder> holderList = new ArrayList<Holder>();

    private class Holder {      
        Path path;
        Paint paint;

        Holder(int color, float width) {
            path = new Path();
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
            paint.setColor(color);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        }
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        holderList.add(new Holder(color, width));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (Holder holder : holderList) {
            canvas.drawPath(holder.path, holder.paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                holderList.add(new Holder(color,width));
                holderList.get(holderList.size() - 1).path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                holderList.get(holderList.size() - 1).path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void resetPaths() {
        for (Holder holder : holderList) {
            holder.path.reset();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBrushColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

And I call it by:

```
DrawView pic = findViewById(R.id.draw);
pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the displayed image size first and then clamp the eventX and eventY to the bound of the displayed image. Code as below:

```
   int imageViewH=imageView.getMeasuredHeight();//height of imageView
   int imageViewW =imageView.getMeasuredWidth();//width of imageView
   int drawableH =imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();//original height of underlying image
   int drawableW=imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();//original width of underlying image
   int displayH, displayW;  // the shown height and width of the picture.
   int leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY; // the shown edges of the picture.
   if (imageViewH/drawableH <= imageViewW/drawableW){
       displayW = drawableW*imageViewH/drawableH;//rescaled width of image within ImageView
       displayH = imageViewH;
       leftX = (imageViewW - displayW)/2; // left edge of the displayed image.
       rightX = leftX + displayW; // right edge of the displayed image.
       topY = 0; // top edg
       bottomY = displayH; // bottom edge.
   }else{
       displayH = drawableH*imageViewW/drawableH;//rescaled height of image within ImageView
       displayW = imageViewW;
       leftX = 0; // left edge of the displayed image.
       rightX = displayW; // right edge of the displayed image.
       topY = (imageViewH - displayH)/2; // top edg
       bottomY = topY + displayH; // bottom edge.
   }
   //TODO: clamp the eventX and eventY to the bound of leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY
```

Note: the code should be used only after your ImageView has its measured height and a drawable.

Comment: yes , I can return the width and height after zooming. Sorry , I guess the code is put in main activity? and would you mind explain a bit about how to set the canvas after I got the H, W, leftX, rightX, topY, bottomY? Thanks

Comment: I think the code can be used in onTouchEvent, but I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient way. And this is a method to calculate the displayed picture bound without zooming, you need to change the calculation after zooming.

Comment: I have tested for putting the code to the custom view touch down case, but is that mean I need to pass in the imageView too from the Main Activity? as imageview is not exist in the custom draw view , and also the clamp event X Y means check whether it exceed the area before add the draw holder list? Sorry for so many question.  Thanks for your help

Comment: No, you don't need to pass imageView. Since you use the code in DrawView, imageView equals "this".  Clamping event X Y means to make sure the parameters that you pass to the path.moveTo() and path.lineTo() method  won't exceed the area of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width of your DrawView programmatically to ImageView's width, if in ImageView's properties there's a true attribute adjustViewBounds.

Comment: Thanks, I added the adjustViewBound in my xml now, would be much better if there is some code about "set a width of your DrawView programmatically to ImageView's width"

Comment: I think you can restrict area of line drawing in: MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                holderList.get(holderList.size() - 1).path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;